# What happened to the accepted check mark?

Tags: bug, accepted-answer

This question [Add multiple items to a listbox on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3896723/719186) is three years old and does not have an accepted answer.

But, if you look at the user's profile, the question *looks* like it has an accepted answer since it has a yellow value in the green box:

[image]

Furthermore, the user has been gone for three years, but they got the 2 points for accepting an answer:

[image]

All the numbers add up to their 38 point reputation and the user never unaccepted an answer.  The question itself does not have any deleted answers on it.

The answer from EMP shows that person did receive the [+15 points](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20336/emp?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=25) for that answer:

[image]

So what happened to the check mark on EMP's posted answer?

Comment: Shouldn't you be making Christmas cookies or something?

Comment: Blind guess that it's some kind of question merging issue in which a question of his with an accepted answer was merged into another question.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Be careful, the word _"Christmas"_ might strike up some kind of debate. I think you meant _"Holiday cookies"_.

Comment: @SeanWM Be careful, the word *"Holiday"* is derived from Holy Day.  I think you meant *"December cookies"*.  :-)

Comment: @SeanWM - Nah, I don't go for that PC stuff.  In my house it's Christmas, and I have a Christmas Tree and I get Christmas Day off from work.  And I hope my Jewish friends celebrate Chaunakah, and not Generic Holiday.

Comment: When my accepted answer was merged I lost the +15 (is bitter) so if they still have the +15 it sounds like it's not that

Comment: As an aside: the "A" next to "09:43 accepted A EMP" at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3896723/timeline (in Oct 9 '10), also still links to EMP's answer.

Comment: According to [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/156208/question-and-answer-links-for-question-id-3896723), the accepted answer ID (3896392) is lower than the question ID (3896723). Post ID 3896392 [doesn't seem to exist in the database](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/156210/all-posts-with-id-3896392).

Comment: Have you checked if he as won -2 reps on a later day by unaccepting the answer?

Comment: @user2284570 If you go to the user's [reputation page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/440194/codie-vincent?tab=reputation), you can see they never had minus points ever.

Comment: @LarsTech : Well maybe in his case the bug could be he unaccepted the answer without loosing any points...